# Accessing positions of marker and places with Google Maps API JS

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation

I'm having a problem accessing geolocation positions of markers and places.

Basically I am creating a marker for a user that has a position in the center of the map. Then I am running the `geolocation.watchPosition` function, in which I am updating the `userMarker` position.  So with every tick done by `watchPosition`, I am updating the location of the userMarker to their current location.  I am also doing a very similar thing with some `places` that I am searching within a given radius. The search is run with each tick of `watchPosition`, and markers are given to each `place`.

Visually, all markers are in the correct locations and update in the correct locations, so they are positioning right.  The problem is that when I try to just print the positions of the markers to the console, using `console.log(userMarker.getPosition())`, I am returned the marker's `LatLng` object, but it empty and looks like this: `_.E {}`.

I basically just want to know what am I doing wrong to access the marker positions and why? This can't just be how the objects are, it's definitely got to be something I am doing wrong.

Here is part of the code:

```
function updateMap(){
  //navigator is passed a callback to handle return position
  navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(watchPositionCallback);
}


/* HELPER FUNCTIONS AND CALLBACKS */

// callback for watchPosition() used to handle the returned position data
// as well as run searches
function watchPositionCallback(position){
  var pos = {
    lat: position.coords.latitude,
    lng: position.coords.longitude
  }

  //new google maps LatLng object
  var currentLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.lat, pos.lng);

  //update request object to be sent to nearBySearch()
  //with the currentLocation object as the specified location
  nearByChurchSearchRequest.location = currentLocation;
  nearByStoreSearchRequest.location = currentLocation;

  // center the map on the currentLocation object
  // and update userMarker position
  map.setCenter(currentLocation);
  userMarker.setPosition(currentLocation);

  console.log(userMarker.getPosition()); // returns _.E {}

  // initialize new PlacesServices
  placesChurchService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  placesStoreService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

  // service methods used to search nearby queries based on the requests
  placesChurchService.nearbySearch(nearByChurchSearchRequest, searchCallback);
  placesStoreService.nearbySearch(nearByStoreSearchRequest, searchCallback);
}
```

PS: I have also tried `getCurrentLocation()` and that doesn't change anything either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the methods on the LatLong object

your call to userMarker.getPosition() returns a LatLng object.

use .lat() and .lng() on this object as seen here

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng

```js
var pos = userMarker.getPosition();
console.log( pos.lat(), pos.lng() );
```

Comment: I see now.  You have to call on the method to return it, its not just static.... thanks for the help!